# Edit-text dots to be filled when typed

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

[image: Enter the Password Image]

I want to add edit text like shown, it has to have pre-fixed 6 small empty dots which will be filled when we type something

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Comment: Try [PasswordTransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod). You can search for how to use it. You may also need to look at text spans to make it all work.